# Problems with tkinter grid layout in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing the Angela Yu 100 days of code python course and im having trouble with the grid layout in tkinter package. I don't understand why my Entry objects aren't directly under each other. I used the same padding and size values as in the course and i tried to change them to look better but the password entry and the add button are more on the left then other entries while they have the same column number in the grid function. Thank u for ur help ^^

Here is the code i used for interface:

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

logo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
image = Canvas(width=200, height=200, highlightthicknes=0)
image.create_image(100, 100, image=logo)
image.grid(column=1, row=0)

website = Label(text="Website:")
website.grid(column=0, row=1)

email = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email.grid(column=0, row=2)

password = Label(text="Password:")
password.grid(column=0, row=3)

website_blank = Entry(width=36)
website_blank.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)
website_blank.focus()

email_blank = Entry(width=36)
email_blank.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
email_blank.insert(0, "aleksander.jaloszynski@gmail.com")

password_blank = Entry(width=21)
password_blank.grid(column=1, row=3)

generate_password = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_password.grid(column=2, row=3)

add = Button(text="Add", width=36, command=save)
add.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

And here is how it looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkE7D.png)

Comment: Add `sticky='w'` to all `.grid(...)` for those entries.

Comment: Thank u it worked. I needed to change same widths and now it looks just how i wanted ^^